# PHP Symfony webpack encore build does not contain all files

Tags: php, symfony, webpack

currently I am writing a PHP application using Symfony 5. The project's build is created using webpack encore, in the root directory I got the `assets` directory which contains all the files (.js, .css, images) that should be included in the build output created by webpack. This directory is located in the `public` directory after I run the `encore dev` script and whenever I run this command the output directory contains all the files stored in the `assets`. But the problem is that when I run the project and navigate to `locahost:8000`, open the dev tools, and open `sources` tab, the build directory contains all the files, but when I for example navigate to `localhost:8000/post/new` it's missing some of this files, seems like it somehow fetched the old `build` directory. My webpack configuration file looks like that

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addLoader(      {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      ],
    },)
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    .copyFiles({
                 from: './assets/images',
        
                 // optional target path, relative to the output dir
                 to: 'images/[path][name].[ext]',
        
                 // if versioning is enabled, add the file hash too
                 //to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        
                 // only copy files matching this pattern
                 //pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/
             })

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Do I need to somehow tell weback that all the files from build directory should be included?

EDIT
Okay, so I checked the console for `localhost:8000/post/new` and it looks like that

```
GET http://localhost:8000/post/build/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8000/post/icon.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

So Symfony is trying to fetch these files from `/post` instead of `/`. How can I prevent it?

Comment: The problem seems to be how you are loading your assets, using a relative path instead of an absolute one. Take a look at [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack) (scroll down to the template part). The relevant portion is the `encore_entry_*` functions. If you can still not solve it, post the relevant part of the template.

Comment: How do you reference the file in twig?  You should be using the asset helper ie. `<img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" alt="logo">`

Comment: Also what is in your config/packages/assets.yaml file?  It needs a key for the json_manifest_path to the manifest.json file location.  It should be there by default when you installed encore, but it's needed for file copying and final path resolution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this OP? I'm struggling with the same thing

Answer (score -1):

Inside `app.js`, you should include scss file

```
import './app.scss';
```

Are you adding assets in twig like this? If Yes, then It will work

In Head

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

And In Body

```
{% block javascripts %}
    { encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What does scss compilation have to do with images?